Vue throws an error due to Multiple spaces found when I try to align a commment
I am trying to comment some Vue code on a template like this:
showSelectedValue: {                // ------- showSelectedValue -------
    type: Boolean,                  // Switches between showing the
    default: true,                  // selected items or the placeholder
},                                  // name. Defaults to true.

However Vue trowsseveral errors saying
 74:25  error  Multiple spaces found before '// ------- sho...'  stylistic/no-multi-spaces
 75:23  error  Multiple spaces found before '// Switches be...'  stylistic/no-multi-spaces
 76:23  error  Multiple spaces found before '// selected it...'  stylistic/no-multi-spaces
 77:7   error  Multiple spaces found before '// name. Defau...'  stylistic/no-multi-spaces

How can I solve this, and still keep the comments aligned?

This is linter error, not vue. Vue is UI lib and not responsible for this kind of things.  You can configure a linter the way you want to suit your code style. That it comes from "stylistic" plugin means it's not even related to code quality, just imposes an opinion on the style

@EstusFlask The project is not mine, it's an open source project, so there is no workarround other than proposing the owner to disable stylistic or this part of it?

What's your intention regarding this project? You can modify eslint config according to your liking if you fork it for your needs, or you're supposed to follow the rules that were imposed by the owner if you contribute to it. FWIW the comment formatting is not conventional

@EstusFlask I was trying to contribute to the public project, I'll contact the owner. Comment formatting conventions? Which convention do you recomend here?

Use jsdoc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551578/how-can-i-properly-document-vue-properties-with-type-object-using-jsdoc if it's used in the rest of the project, or just add a multiline comment above the prop like /* ... */ showSelectedValue: {...} for accidental comment. As long as this conforms current eslint rules. This is a guideline for code style to follow. You shouldn't ignore or modify them when you contribute to other projects
